# How account password could be plain text visible in account settings?

Tags: android, security, settings, account, authenticator

It seems that no one has encountered this problem or doesn't talk about it. I implemented authenticator "concept" for an enterprise application. And in a random way, when I navigate to the account settings, instead of account name in the left menu I can see the password in clear text !! It's very strange and I actually can't explain ! As you can see here :

[image: Account settings with password in clear text]

[UPDATE] Some APIs I use :

```
accountManager.addAccount(AuthenticationActivity.ACCOUNT_TYPE, 
    SaurAuthenticator.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, 
    null, null, activity, 
    new OnCreatedAccount(activity, accountManager, handler),
    null);
```

OnCreatedAccount run this

```
Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
String accountName = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
String accountType = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
Log.v(tag, "account created : " + accountName + " - " + accountType);
Account currentAccount = new Account(accountName, accountType);
Log.v(tag, "ask token ");
mAccountManager.getAuthToken(currentAccount, SaurAuthenticator.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE,
    null, mActivity, new OnTokenAcquired(mHandler), null);
```

And my AuthenticationActivity (showing login and password `TextView`) I have a method finishLogin :

```
String accountName = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

final Account account = new Account(accountName, intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));

if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, false)) {
    String authtoken = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
    // Creating the account on the device and setting the auth token we got
    manager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);
    // If do not call setAuthToken cause other unnecessary server call
    manager.setAuthToken(account, SaurAuthenticator.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, authtoken);
    // Force auto sync for this account 
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, DataCacheContract.AUTHORITY, true);
}

  setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

I hope my English is correct :)

Thanks for helping !

Comment: You say "in a random way", do you mean sometimes on the page you see the correct information and sometimes the password? Look at what is populating that menu, where the text is coming from. Without providing code samples of the relevant bits of the application people aren't going to be able to give direct answers.

Comment: Please provide the code you used when implementing the functionality :-)

Comment: Yes, by random I mean sometimes I see the authenticator provider name and less frequently, I see the password.

Comment: Thanks to pay attention :o)
I just push some code !

For information, I already did a modification by "not providing" password in `manager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null /* no more pwd */, null);` API (second arg) without effect !